# How to check if the Username and Password entered by a user to the text boxes match on the records in the database

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I'm using VB.Net with MySQL Database and I want to check if the username and password match on the database values Example: Username= **Admin11** is different from Username= **admin11** when the user entered lowercase "a" and in the database its Uppercase"A" it is wrong. what I want to happen is when the user entered the username that it's not exactly the username in the database values username is incorrect here's my code but it's not working

```
Dim con = New MySqlConnection

con.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;userid=root;password=alpine;port=3305;database=pos_db;pooling=false;SslMode=none"

con.Open()

Dim qry As String = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pos_db.tblusers WHERE Username=@user AND Password=@pass"
Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand(qry, con)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", txtUsername.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", txtPassword.Text)

Dim count As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar())

If count <> 0 Then
    Me.Hide()
    FrmSelect.Show()
Else
    MessageBox.Show("Either username or password in incorrect", "System", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `binary` in your query

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM pos_db.tblusers 
WHERE 
  BINARY Username = @user
  AND BINARY Password = @pass
```

Comment: Mark as answer and update your post with correct answer. Welcome @MarkNartea

Comment: @parkway - can mark as answer if it answered the question, but do not update the original question. Such edits will be rolled back.

Comment: Yes, sir thanks a lot. how can I mark this post as answered, I'm newbie here in StackOverflow

Comment: Did you saw the number 0 at this thread? there are arrow up and down. u press/mousehover the arrow up button

Comment: copy that. sir, may I ask a question why we use binary? for what reason.

Comment: @MarkNartea BINARY is a built-in keyword that after your WHERE clause that forces a comparison for an exact case-sensitive match.. Normally if involve case sensitive i will use this in my query. you no need create vb.net code to check it whether match or not. same goes with php as well

Comment: Thanks, sir for that answer I will treasure that. by the way sir I have a problem again I use the same syntax above on my signup to check if the values entered by the user is already in the database the value that is already in my pos_db.tblusers Username =" MarkJhosephNartea" and when I insert another username with the value of Username ="Markjhosephnartea" it result to runtime error, duplicate entry. how can i fix that? thanks sir on response.

Comment: @MarkNartea i cannot catch up what you mean. duplicate entry?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53608581/vb-net-mysql-how-to-insert-values-to-the-database

Answer (score 0):

thanks A lot to Sir @parkway for helping me, it is the correct query on my question. now I learn new things in programming thanks a lot again sir.

con.Open()

```
        Dim qry As String = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pos_db.tblusers WHERE BINARY Username=@user AND BINARY Password=@pass"
        Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand(qry, con)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", txtUsername.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", txtPassword.Text)

        Dim count As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar())

        If count <> 0 Then
            Me.Hide()
            FrmSelect.Show()
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Either username or password in incorrect", "System", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End If
```

Comment: Please accept @parkway 's answer by clicking the check mark (tick mark) to the left of his answer.

Comment: Thank you Ma'am mary for informing me. :) I'm a newbie here in our community hehe.