# VB.Net MySQL How to insert values to the database

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Pro Devs I'm using VB.Net with MySQL Database and I want to insert values in my DB. Example: I have values in my DB which are **Admin11** but when I insert another value **admin11** I get an error here's my code. by the way, these two methods are in different classes.

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

here's my code to check if Username exists in the database...

Public Sub checkUsernameIfExist()

```
    Dim con = New MySqlConnection
    con.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;userid=root;password=alpine;port=3305;database=pos_db;pooling=false;SslMode=none"

    con.Open()
    Dim query As String = "SELECT Username FROM pos_db.tblusers WHERE BINARY Username=@Users"
    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand(query, con)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Users", frmLogin.txtUser.Text)

    Dim count As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar())

    If count <> 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Username is already taken. Please create a unique one!", "System", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
        Return
    Else
        insertDataToTblUser.insertToLogin()
    End If
    con.Close()
    con.Dispose()
End Sub
```

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

Here's my code in insert values......

Dim con As MySqlConnection

```
Public Sub insertToLogin()
    con = New MySqlConnection
    con.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;userid=root;password=alpine;port=3305;database=pos_db;pooling=false;SslMode=none"

    con.Open()

    Dim qry As String = "INSERT INTO tblUsers (Username,Password,Level) VALUES (@User,@Pass,@lvl)"
    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand(qry, con)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@User", frmLogin.txtUser.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pass", frmLogin.txtPass.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lvl", frmLogin.cmbUserlevel.Text)
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    MessageBox.Show("Sign Up Successful", "System", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)

    con.Close()
    con.Dispose()
End Sub
```

Please help me thanks a lot.

Comment: how your database looks like? is there is primary key is used in the database?

Comment: Yes, Sir, Username is my primary key. but when I insert another value just like what I illustrate on the top I got an error.

Comment: you cannot use the username as primary key. primary should auto increment when you adding a new value.

Comment: @parkway actually you can if you want to, but extra code is needed to ensure that the values are definitely unique. Anything can be a primary key, but of course not everything can be an auto_increment field.

Comment: @MarkNartea what error do you get, exactly?

Comment: Yes, sir, I got your point, but "Admin11" is different from "admin11" the difference is the other one is in uppercase "A" and the other one is in lowercase "a" is it possible to insert that ?

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. What error do you get? Saying "I get an error" is no good if you don't tell us exactly what it is.

Comment: there is two errors for one (Input string was not in a correct format) it highlights the count As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar()). and the second one is duplicate entry for key primary @ADyson

Comment: `count As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar()` fails because your query returns a username (i.e. some text), not a number. Changing to `SELECT Count(Username)` would do the job.

Comment: The second error is likely because mysql varchar fields are case-insensitive by default. your WHERE BINARY workaround will change the output of that one query, but it doesn't change what the field will actually accept. This has been discussed before and solutions proposed - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6448825/sql-unique-varchar-case-sensitivity-question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL unique varchar case sensitivity question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6448825/sql-unique-varchar-case-sensitivity-question)

Comment: thanks sir i apply that.

Comment: @ADyson yes it can but by doing that need to do extra validation for the code. make sure the database structure is in correct way at early stage so that wont face difficulty at the end of the project we built.

Comment: Sir @parkway how can I fix these errors?

Comment: Thanks for help pro devs, I already fix it. thank you very much!. :) especially to Sir, ADyson & Sir parkway.

Answer (score 2):

These solves my problem Thanks to all who help me.

```
CREATE TABLE `pos_db`.`tblForLogin` (
    `Username` VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin NOT NULL UNIQUE, 
    `Password` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `Level` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY(Username)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

[MySQL Reserved Words](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html)

Change your query:

```
Dim qry As String = "INSERT INTO tblUsers (Username,`Password`,`Level`) VALUES (@User,@Pass,@lvl)"
```

Comment: thanks for the help sir. but its not working hehe. this is the error  Input string was not in a correct format. it highlights the Dim count As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar())

Comment: Sorry I don't get the point of this answer. You've put Username, Password and Level in quotes...but none of them appear in the list of reserved words you've linked to.

Comment: @ADyson This answer has added the back tick, which is the escape character in MySql. It is assuming that the error was caused by keywords being used as field names.

Comment: @Mary I'm not disputing that, but my point was that in the answer there is a link to a list of reserved words, but none of the field names above appear in that list. If someone is going to use some documentation to back up their answer, it would make sense if that documentation actually contains the relevant proof. And it's always better to link to the official documentation anyway (which _does_ contain PASSWORD and LEVEL listed as reserved words): https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html